# Show that $M=\{g \in G \mid g^m=e\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $m$ a positive integer. Show that $M=\{g \in G \mid g^m=e\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

What I am thinking about is that our set is the set of all groups generators, since $m$ appears to be the order of $G$ which therefore must be a cyclic group. So, and since each group generated by a single element in a subgroup of $G$, the union of all of these must also be a subgroup.

But...I have not used commutativity yet...of course know that since $G$ is abelian, $g^m h^m = h^m g^m$ for all $h,g \in G$.

How can I do this?

Comment: Suppose $g^m=e=h^n$. Then $(gh)^{mn} = g^{mn}h^{mn}=e^ne^m=e$, so $gh \in M$. Commutativity is needed to make the first equality hold. (I'm assuming that $m$ isn't fixed in your definition, but if it is then you can replace $mn$ with just $m$)

Comment: How would that prove it's a subgroup though?  Or this is just meant to be for showing closure?

Comment: There's a "subgroup theorem" which says that if $H \subseteq G$ is nonempty and closed under the group operation of $G$, then $H$ is a subgroup under that group operation. There might be something in there about $H$ being closed under inverses but for finite groups $g^{-1} = g^{|G| - 1}$ so this is implied by closure under multiplication.

Comment: But what is the point of setting $g^{m}=h^{n}$?

Comment: That's shorthand for "if $g$ raised to the $m$-th power is the identity and $h$ raised to the $n$-th power is the identity". I think @Hayden is confused about whether or not $m$ is fixed and is bringing in $n$ just in case.

Comment: Well that's understandable given the notation of the original problem is a bit confusing after all. I guess he wasn't necessarily stating that 2 elements of $M$ have to be equal right up-front; it's just the case that they will be by the nature of the operation.  But, I get the idea now.  Thanks to ALL!

Comment: @PBJ Yes, T. Gunn is right about what I was going for; you'll see that kind of phrasing very often, as it represents all of the information you need in a concise way. What I showed is that your $M$ is closed under the group operation, and T. Gunn shows how to see closure under inversion as well. Another way is to note that if $g^m=e$, then $(g^{-1})^m=(g^m)^{-1}=e^{-1}=e$.

Answer (score 4):

> Prove that $M=\{g \in G \mid g^m=e\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

*Proof*: $e\in G$ and $e^m=e$ and so, by the definition of the set $M$, we get $e\in M$ which shows that $M\neq \emptyset$.
Let $x,y\in M$. Then $x,y\in G$ such that $x^m=e$ and $y^m=e$. Note that $y^{-1}\in G$ and so, $xy^{-1}\in G$. Moreover,
$$\overbrace{(xy^{-1})^m=x^m(y^{-1})^m}^{\text{since $G$ is abelian. }}=x^m(y^m)^{-1}=ee^{-1}=e.$$

This implies that $xy^{-1}\in M$. Using the [Subgroup Criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180895/subgroup-criterion), the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* The map $x \mapsto x^m$ is a homomorphism $G \to G$. Find its kernel.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote "$m$ appears to be the order of $G$". That is wrong. The number $m$ is the order of one element of $g$. For example, if $G$ is the Klein group, the only non-cyclic abelian group of order $4$, then there are three elements of $G$ of order $2$, and $2$ is not the order of $G$. Likewise if $G$ is the cyclic group of order $4$, then $G$ has one element of order $2$, and again $2$ is not the order of $G$.

The essential point is not that $g^m h^m = h^m g^m,$ but rather that $(gh)^m = g^m h^m.$ For example:
$$
(gh)^6 = (gh)(gh)(gh)(gh)(gh)(gh) = (gggggg)(hhhhhh).
$$
If $g^6=e$ and $h^6=e$, then this proves $(gh)^6=e$, so $gh$ is a member of that same set, and so that set is closed under multiplication. You also need to show it's closed under inversion.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h \in H$, then $h \in G$, so $H \subseteq G$. Then we just need to check that $H$ satisfies the group axioms.

For $h_1$ and $h_2$ in $H$, and assuming that $m$ is fixed in your definition, we have
$$(h_1 h_2 )^m = h_1 h_2 \cdots h_1 h_2 \text{ ($m$ times)},$$
then you can use the fact $h_1$ and $h_2$ commute to get $h_1^m h_2^m = e$, hence $H$ is closed. Now check the other axioms.