# Showing $\{g \in G: g^n=1\}$ is a cyclic subgroup of cyclic $G$ of order $n$ for $|G|=nk, k\in\Bbb N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

> Show that $H=\{g \in G: g^n=1\}$ is a cyclic subgroup of cyclic group $G$ of order $n$ where $|G|=d$ and $d=nk$ for some $k \in \Bbb N$.

I could have used Cauchy's theorem but then I realised that this would be an overkill.

So

1. I proved that every subgroup of a cylic group is cyclic.
2. Then I proved that $H\leq G$ so $H$ is cyclic by (1). $1 \in H$ so $H \neq \phi$ and $g^{k}(\neq 1)\in H$. So, $|H|\geq 2$.

**Now I am stuck at the point on how to prove that $|H|=n$ in an elementary way? Any help?**

Note: it's [not a duplicate of this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2241109/104041) as there the question was to prove that it subgroup which I did by myself. Moreover, that is a question on commutative group and asked to prove that it is a subgroup and here the question is on order of the subgroup.

Comment: Have we assumed $G$ is cyclic? Also, have you shown that $H$ is a group?

Comment: Yes, I proved that H is a subgroup.

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate as there the question was to prove that it subgroup which I did by myself. Moreover, that is a question on commutative group.

Comment: Why are you putting me question as duplicate one??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $H$ is cyclic, $H = \langle h\rangle$ for some $h \in G$ with $h^n = 1$. Thus the order of $H$ must divide $n$. Conversely, if $g$ is a generator of $G$ (i.e. $G = \left<g\right>$), then $g^{ik}$ is in $H$ for every $i = 0,1,...,n-1$ since $(g^{ik})^n = g^{id} = 1$. Since each $g^{ik}$ is distinct, there are at least $n$ elements of $H$. The only number greater than or equal to $n$ that divides $n$ is $n$, so $|H| = n$.

Comment: The OP showed that $H$ is a subgroup, and also that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic; these are both correct. I do not understand what is not warranted about these points.

Comment: Ah yes, I apologize, I assumed that $G$ was cyclic given OP's first point. I will change my answer accordingly        Edit: never mind per OP's comment

Comment: Hi, I have edited it. G is cyclic. Sorry for the confusion if G is not cyclic then it is not true e.g $D_8$ then consider $n=2$.

Comment: Just a quick question, for abelian groups H is a subgroup but is it also correct that it would be a cyclic group?

Comment: No, it would not necessarily be cyclic. A simple example is the Klein four-group $G = \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ with $n=2$, since the subgroup $H$ would then be the whole group $G$ which is not cyclic. Another example, take $G = \mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_4$ with $n=2$ to get $H$ again isomorphic to the Klein four-group. Clearly many similar such constructions are possible.