# Suppose $G$ is a finite group and let $X_m = \{x \in G\mid x^m = e \}$. Then $G$ is Abelian if and only if for each $m$: $ |X_m|\mid |G| $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I was reading Frobenius theorem and I came to this question:

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and let $X_m = \{x \in G\mid x^m = e \}$. Then
$G$ is Abelian if and only if for each $m$:
$$
|X_m|\mid |G|
$$
(order of $X_m$ divides the order of group)

I can prove the "only if" part but I don't have any idea for the "if"

I even tried to find a counterexample but I wasn't successful.

any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your proof for "if"? One direction is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241109/show-that-m-g-in-g-mid-gm-e-is-a-subgroup-of-g). If $G$ is abelian, then $|X_m|$ divides the order of $G$ by Lagrange.

Comment: sorry I meant the "only if" part by Lagrange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The converse need not be true. The quaternion group $Q_8=\{1,-1,i,-i,j,-j,k,-k\}$ satisfies
$$
X_1=\{1\},\; X_2=\{1, -1\},\; X_4=Q_8,  
$$
and $X_m=\{1\}$  for all $m$ with $2\nmid m$. So $X_m$ divides $|Q_8|=8$ for all $m\ge 1$, but $Q_8$ is not abelian.

Comment: What is the difference between $X_1$ and $X_k$ ? Is this a typo?

Comment: Ok. Now i got it

Comment: The statement about $X_m$ being trivial is not written right. Like $X_8$ is the same as $X_4$ in being all of $Q_8$. You have $m \neq 2$ where you should have said $m$ not divisible by $2$.